# Is there a way to run a single Jenkins job over and over again?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to run a single Jenkins job over and over again within a certain time period? Or run a single job for particular 100 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins lets you schedule jobs .. use the "Build Periodically" checkbox and in the Schedule add a Cron expression

If you know how long your job takes to run, you can schedule it to run over and over without taking too many resources... in the expression below you can run the job every "n" minutes (replace n with your time ).

```
* */n * * *
```

Comment: No Problem , if it solved your question I will appreciate if you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

use Build periodically and select your days to run and time interval accordingly. Examples I want to run a job for every two hours from Monday to Friday                                                                         # once every two hours every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
H 9-16/2 * * 1-5